# My django template navbar is not working properly

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-urls

Here I have two template called base.html and contact.html.contact.html extends the base.html.I only have these two templates.When i click blog or about it scrolls me to the about section or blog section.

But the problem is while going to the contact page and when I try to click the any of the url in nav bar home or about from contact page it doesn't go anywhere.How can I solve this?

When I am in the base.html it has url `127.0.0.1/#blogs` but in contact page
`127.0.0.1/contact/#blogs`

Sorry for my bad english.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    abt_me = Me.objects.order_by('-created').first()

    return render(request,'base.html',{'abt':abt_me})

def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Hello {}!. Your message has been sent successfully'.format(contact.full_name))
            return redirect('contact')

    return render(request,'contact.html',{'form':form})
```

base.html

```
  <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">
              <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                <li><a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#blogs" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>


              </ul>
            </nav>
<div class="site-section" id="about">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
```

contact.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
<section class="site-section">
```

Comment: Why *should* it go anywhere? The links are all to the same page. if that page doesn't contain the blogs or about section, there isn't anywhere for it to go.

Comment: @DanielRoseman then there is no solution for this ?

Comment: Of course there's a solution. But what do you actually want to happen?

Comment: @DanielRoseman what can I do then ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: when I click the nav links from `contact.html` i want to go to that clicked link.Right now it is only working from `base.html`

Answer (score 0):

your home page should be 127.0.0.1/ and its this; path('',views.home,name='home'),

maybe you can try change base.html and contact.html including.Because your home method work base.html and it should be include extends

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<li><a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
```

with this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
```